# Why is my bootstrap background not showing?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I cannot see why my background image is not showing. I've tried even eliminating the css styling just to try and get the image to pop up somewhere. The image is recognized and found just fine, but all I get is a white background.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block page_content %}
<div class="view" style="background-image: url('17973908.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover; background-position:center center;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <h1>Blog</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-fb" href="#" type="button" role="button"><i class="shadow rounded-circle fab fa-facebook fa-2x" style="color:#0099FF;"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">
                <a class="btn-floating btn-lg btn-fb" href="#" type="button" role="button"><i class="shadow rounded fab fa-linkedin fa-2x" style="color:#0099FF;"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        {% for post in posts %}
        <div class="shadow card" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2><a href="{% url 'blog_detail' post.pk%}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title">
                    <small>
                        {{ post.created_on.date }} |&nbsp;
                        Categories:&nbsp;
                        {% for category in post.categories.all %}
                        <a href="{% url 'blog_category' category.name %}">
                            {{ category.name }}
                        </a>&nbsp;
                        {% endfor %}
                    </small>
                </div>
                <div class="card-text">
                    <p>{{ post.body | slice:":400" }}...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question I cannot reproduce your setup, so here are just some suggestions for trying to find the problem.

1. Make sure the image is loaded properly - open DevTools with F12 and check Console and Network tabs for errors
2. Remove your custom CSS, i.e., at least the `view` class
3. Make sure the div on which the image is set has a width and height larger than 0
4. Make sure no element is on top of the image div - try setting a high `z-index`, e.g., `z-index: 9999;`
5. Remove surrounding HTML elements, especially elements inside the image div

P.S.: I directly copied your code into the Bootstrap Starter template and changed the `background-image` url to some random image from the internet and it worked.

Comment: Apparently, it was just a bad image. I just swapped the image out with a different one and it worked. Thanks, sometimes you just need someone else to say the thing you should have thought of!

Comment: Was the image successfully `fixed` when you tried this out. the only issue I am having now is that everything else is being ignored. `fixed`, `no-repeat`, all being ignored... Any suiggestions?

Comment: Yeah, everything seems to be working as it should be. Try removing your custom CSS and apply only the styles that are being ignored. Also make sure that it is not a problem with CSS specificity - try adding `!important` at the end of CSS values. But if this is the problem, try to solve it without `!important`, use this only as a last resort and for testing.